# Compute the frequency of the event that the second RC4 key byte is 0x00

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption

I want generate more than 10000 random keys K (of 32 bytes) and need to use them to RC4 and need to Compute the frequency of the event that the second RC4 key byte is 0x00.

I have coded this solution am I right?

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main (void)
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int sbox [256];
        int key [32];

        char *key_str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        int tmp = 0;
        int n = 0;

        fprintf (stdout,"Key string is %s\n",key_str);
        for (i=0; i<32; i++)
        {
            key[i] = key_str[i%5];
            sbox[i] = i;
        }

        j = 0;
        for (i=0; i<32; i++)
        {
            j += sbox[i] + key[i];
            j = j % 32;
            tmp = sbox[i];
            sbox[i] = sbox[j];
            sbox[j] = tmp;
        }


        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        for (n=0; n<10000; n++)
        {

            i++;
            i = i % 32;
            j += sbox[i];
            j = j % 32;
            tmp = sbox[i];
            sbox[i] = sbox[j];
            sbox[j] = tmp;

            if ((n == 0) || (n == 99) || (n == 999) || (n == 9999))
            {
                fprintf (stdout,"byte %d is %0x00\n",
                        n+1,sbox[(sbox[i] + sbox[j]) % 32]);
            }
        }       
        return (0);
    }
```

Comment: Why would the odds *not* be 1/256?

Comment: i didnt get you

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  If your keys are truly being randomly generated, you would expect about 1/256th of the keys you generate to have 0x00 as the second byte.

Comment: what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Because RC4 has that weakness.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article on RC4: "The best such attack is due to Itsik Mantin and Adi Shamir who showed that the second output byte of the cipher was biased toward zero with probability 1/128 (instead of 1/256). This is due to the fact that if the third byte of the original state is zero, and the second byte is not equal to 2, then the second output byte is always zero. Such bias can be detected by observing only 256 bytes."

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, but the following code produces 10,000 random 32-byte keys and then counts the number of times a key is generated that has a second byte as zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int run_test() {
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        char buf[32];

        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            buf[j] = rand();
        }

        if (buf[1] == 0x00) { c++; }
    }

    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%d", run_test());
}
```

**Disclaimer**: A CSPRNG is not used here, don't actually generate keys this way.

Comment: This is the problem statement: `Implement RC4, Generate
more than 10000 random keys K (of 32 bytes) and use them to
RC4. Compute the frequency of the event that the second RC4 key byte is 0x00.`

Comment: I was able to implement random keys but I'm not sure how to use these keys in RC4